# How to get the Teams User Id for Teams Interop Using Azure Communication Services

Tags: azure, azure-communication-services

I have created a Microsoft Teams Meeting from the Microsoft Teams Client
e.g of meeting link: `https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/....`

Note: I am already able to join a call using the external users taking reference from this
[Create and manage access tokens for Teams external users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/identity/access-token-teams-external-users?tabs=windows&pivots=programming-language-javascript)
use the tokens in [CallComposite](https://azure.github.io/communication-ui-library/?path=/story/composites-call-with-chat-basicexample--basic-example) Component

Now,
I am trying to start a Teams Call from/within our website for the link mentioned above. I already have an authorized Microsoft OAuth User and got the accessToken and refresh token.

I've retrieved the Azure Communication Services access token following this [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/manage-teams-identity?pivots=programming-language-javascript). However, I cannot retrieve an Azure Communication Services User Id.

Just for quick testing, I am testing the credentials on the following [page](https://azure.github.io/communication-ui-library/?path=/story/composites-call-with-chat-basicexample--basic-example).

I've also raised a Microsoft support ticket [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/comments/1141433/view.html)

Answer (score 0):

The answer really depends on your scenario.

[Create and manage access tokens for Teams external users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/identity/access-token-teams-external-users?tabs=windows&pivots=programming-language-javascript)

- This article describes how you can create and manage identities that can connect a Teams call and when they do, they appear as "external users"

[Quickstart: Set up and manage access tokens for Teams users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/manage-teams-identity?pivots=programming-language-javascript)

- This article describes how a Teams user can use their AAD identity to get an ACS token (and therefore can use ACS to join calls)
- In this case, there is no ACS identity associated with the Teams user and the ID is the [`oid` (Object ID)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens) claim of the AAD identity. (so there is no `Azure Communication Services User Id`)
- You say you've retrieved the ACS access token already so you must have the `oid` at your disposal.

If you're looking for a way to convert the `oid` claim to `MicrosoftTeamsUserIdentifier` and back, check out this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/concepts/identifiers?pivots=programming-language-javascript#raw-id-representation).